# Guard not redirecting after done already a redirect

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, ngrx-router-store

I got some weird issue with a guard routing. 
The situation is as follows: 
Page A has a guard on it where the guard checks if it has everything to access that page. If not it will redirect to page B to get everything it needs selecting a client for example. 
When that user navigates back to page A without the right information it gets redirected back to Page B. 
This is where everything goes wrong because the user isn't allowed to go to Page A I return a false from the guard and do a redirect. 
But my store says that the route is Page A but because I deny navigation I am still on Page B.

This situation looks like the following in code:

**Guard**

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
              state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {

    if (got_what_i_need) {
      return true;
    } else {

        this.store.dispatch(new RouterActions.Go({
          path: ['pageB']




    }
    return false;

  }
```

**Routes**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: RoutePaths.pageA, loadChildren: './pageA', canActivate: [PortalDetectionGuard] },
  { path: RoutePaths.PageB, loadChildren: './pageB'},
```

Anyone an idea what I am doing wrong here? 
Also whenever I return false the current page also doesn't get destroyed or reinitialized.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an another navigation strategy:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    if (got_what_i_need) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['page-B'])
    }
    return false;
}
```

You need to insert the router in the Guard's constructor for this.

```
  constructor(private navigationService: NavigationService)
```

If that does not work, maybe the "got_what_i_need" part is the cause.

Comment: I already tried to use router.navigate directly but it has the same results.